# Dart: why do class methods work the same using this.variableName or variableName?

Tags: dart

I was wondering if it was purposefully designed to be able to use two different ways in writing class methods, inside of which an instance property is refered to, this might sound vague so I provided a little code snippet to illustrate my point.

At first, I was under the impression that we use `this.age` instead of `age` because the latter would modify all the instances `age` property, but when I tried with & without the `this.` keyword it only changed the instance on which the method `changeAge` is used.

Is there a purpose for having two ways of writing this?

```
class Person{
  String name;
  int age;
  Person({this.name, this.age});
  
  void changeAge(int a){
    this.age = a; // why can this be written: age = a; and achieve same result?
  }
  }
void main(){
  Person foo = Person(name: 'foo', age: 16);
  Person bar = Person(name: 'bar', age: 30);
  foo.changeAge(99);
  print(foo.age); // prints 99
  print(bar.age); // prints 30 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart uses the lexical scope to look up the meaning of identifiers.
When you write `age`, the compiler:

1. Checks first whether there is a local variable names `age` in the current function.
2. Then it checks whether there is a parameter, or type parameter, of the surrounding function named `age`.
3. Then it checks whether there is a declaration named `age` in the surrounding class (which there is in `Person`). This can be either an instance declaration or a static declaration.
4. Then it checks for a the type parameter of the class named `age`, if the class is generic.
5. Then it checks the current library for a top-level declaration named `age`.
6. Then it checks for an imported declaration named `age`.

If it finds any declaration, then it considers `age` as referring to that.
If what it found was a static declaration, then `age` is equivalent to `ClassName.age`.
If it found an instance declaration, then `age` is equivalent to `this.age`.

If it found nothing, and it's inside an instance method, then it treats `age` as `this.age`, and it's an error if there is no inherited `age` instance member in the current class.

So, in this case, the reason `age = a;` and `this.age = a;` is the same is that `age` resolves to the instance variable of the surrounding class.

You don't *have* to write `this.age`, but you can, which is why you can write your `changeAge` method as:

```dart
  void changeAge(int age){
    this.age = age; // `this.age` is the field, `age` refers to the parameter.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"The this keyword is used to refer the current class object. It indicates the current instance of the class, methods, or constructor. It can be also used to call the current class methods or constructors. It eliminates the uncertainty between class attributes and the parameter names are the same. If we declare the class attributes same as the parameter name, that situation will create ambiguity in the program, then the this keyword can remove the ambiguity by prefixing the class attributes. It can be passed as an argument in the class method or constructors."

In short, Dart will search for a class property called "age" if you don't  use this.

If your function  has already declared a variable called "age" dart will refer to that variable. To refer to the class property instead, now you can use the this keyword

Changing a class property  of an instance won't  affect the property  of other instances. It has nothing  to do with the this keyword.  That's  just an OOP principle, it's  the same on other OOP language .

Your foo and bar are completely  independent instances of Person